# How can I assign a custom CSS file name when building a VITE application?

Tags: css, sass, build, export, vite

Is it possible to build in VITE and use `application-name.css` or `my-site-name.css`?

VITE has an option to build a custom JS file, but not a custom CSS or SCSS file (for export).

https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode

VITE Build name: `style.css`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 23):

This is my **vite.config.js** for have custom css file name:

```
   rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          if (assetInfo.name == 'style.css')
            return 'customname.css';
          return assetInfo.name;
        },
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed code, work great,
The vite can hander build simple easy 

Is it possible to build the style NOT minify? (for preview)

Comment: Great answer for CSS, [assetFileNames](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-assetfilenames) will handle assets such as CSS and SVG files. Other useful ones to know about are: [`dir`](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-dir), and [`entryFileNames`](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-entryfilenames) and [`chunkFileNames`](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-chunkfilenames) for JS.

Comment: can I move the generated style.css file to a css folder like `return "css/style.css"`?

Answer (score 7):

This seems more robust in latest versions. The current solution was not working for me originally.

```
build: {
    lib: {
      name: 'LIBRARYNAME',
      fileName: 'LIBRARYNAME',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: "LIBRARYNAME.[ext]",
      },
    },
  },
```

This produces:

```
dist/LIBRARYNAME.css      
dist/LIBRARYNAME.cjs.js  
dist/LIBRARYNAME.cjs.js.map 
dist/LIBRARYNAME.umd.js   
dist/LIBRARYNAME.umd.js.map
```

Without name and filename, the JS files end up default names. Without the rollup option, the CSS file ends up `style.css`.

Comment: This worked for me with vite@3.0.9. As per https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-lib if not specified the `build.lib.fileName` is derived from the `name` property in your `package.json`.

Comment: in the new version of vite like vite@4.5.4 it doesn't work.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I had to use `index.css` instead of `style.css` as vite was building me css with that name (prehash) and then apply the rollup.

so this worked for me:

in `vite.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */

export default {
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          if (assetInfo.name == "index.css") return "css/styles.css";
          return assetInfo.name;
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

this also puts the css file in the new css folder inside the dist folder automatically.