# How to set the names of Vite build JS and CSS bundle names in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am using Vite+Vue3 and JavaScript to build a SPA. The problem is that whenever I run `npm run build` I after making changes I get a .css and .js with different names that look like they are generated from some hash. I want to have fixed names for both for example code.js and styles.css. I have read the Vite Documentation and cannot seem to find what I am looking for.

I have read the documentation for Vite+Vue and cannot seem to find the answer. I want to be able to specify the resultant file names for Javascript and CSS whenever I run `npm run build`.

When I run `npm build`, I get the following files in `dist/assets/`:

- `index.c14cf232.js`
- `index.a6c8e3b2.css`

The second part of these names keeps changing whenever I update the up. I want the names to be predictable.
For example:

- `index.code.js`
- `index.styles.js`

No matter how many times I run `npm build`.

Is there a Vite config setting that allows me do this?

Comment: Why do you want to have the same hashes every time?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to have the same file names every time because I am using the apps in my WordPress plugin. The Vue files will be enqueued using PHP based on file names.

Answer (score 10):

As it turns out this is not very hard to do at all. The only reason why I couldn't find a solution is because of the terminology used in the bundling world which I was not familiar with. These are part of Vite's RollUp options. All one needs to do is add the following options to vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                dir: '~/plugin/assets/',
                entryFileNames: 'plugin.js',
                assetFileNames: 'plugin.css',
                chunkFileNames: "chunk.js",
                manualChunks: undefined,
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This outputs the build bundle into the ~/plugins/assets folder with them having the same names.

Comment: Beware this will produce near-duplicate filenames and build/output any .svg file as .css. e.g. vue.svg and tailwind-source.css became respectively plugin.css plugin2.css. [Here's a useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69327733/1717535) to make things more dynamic.

Comment: This is the best answer I've found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69614671/vite-without-hash-in-filename

Comment: It works for small project with only css and js for now. thanks.